# Android socket on server stopped

Tags: java, android, swing, sockets

I'm writing an **TCP client** in **Android** that sends data to a **Java** server. I'm now adding validation for when the server's not available and I got stuck on what to do when the server is killed suddenly (I'm actually exitting the server with `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` since is a test server).

The issue is that when I close the server, the the client doesn't throws any exception whenever I write to the `OutputStream` nor when I read from the `InputStream`.

```
// This is inside a try block, catching IOException, and finally block closes all streams
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while (mRun) {
    String response = in.readLine();
    Message message = Message.obtain();

    if (response != null && message != null) {
        message.obj = response;
        mHandler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Also, when I close the server, the system keeps logging about 10-20 of the following logs per second, or maybe more:

```
dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 6% free 9377K/9920K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
```

**ALSO** I have another thread that attempts to write to the `Sockets`'s `OutputStream` by using `PrintWriter`:

```
if(out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Writing to output stream...");
        //...
```

And it seems to keep executing, which  means `checkError()` is returning false

I'm new to `Socket` programming, so an explanation of why should I do what you tell me to do would be nice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028620/java-sockets-and-dropped-connections ?

Comment: but are you able to detect that it is already closed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the following line

```
while (mRun) {
```

to

```
while (response = in.readLine() && socket.isConnected()) {
```